# Determine which condition was passed in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

is there anyway i can tell which condition was passed .

```
if ( a || b ){
    //do common operations to both

    if (a){
    //do a operation
    }
     if (b) {
      //do be operation
    }
}
```

feels like I'm doing the same thing over with the inner conditions. How can avoid doing that? is there a way to know which condition passed and proceed with it. some thing ..

```
if ( a || b ){
        //do common operations to both

        if first condition was passed{
        //do a operation
        }
        if second condition was passed{
          //do b operation
        }
    }
```

Some operations are expensive to be repeated unnecessarily. Thanks.

Comment: else statement instead of second if

Comment: you can also use a switch case http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php or (nested) ternary.

Comment: imagine i have several (or conditions) not just two.. you get it right??

Comment: @fred how do i deal with common functionalities using switch?

Comment: So you can have `a||b||c||d||q` what should happen if it is `s` in that example?

Comment: can you rephrase the question? i don't quite get it.. do you mean the number of the conditions?.. just say i have four conditions

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the value **at the time of condition/expression checking**. you can easily know which condition is passed and proceed with it.

```
$a = 5; //true
$b = 0; //false

if ( $a_t = $a || $b_t= $b ){
    //do common operations to both
    $both = $a+$b;
    if ($a_t){
    //do a operation
        $a = $a+5;
    }
     if ($b_t) {
         $b = $b+5;
      //do be operation
    }
}
echo "a=$a & b= $b & both=$both";
```

**Edit:** It should also work with `isset()`

```
$a = 5; //true
$b = 0; //false

if ( $a_t = isset($a) || $b_t= isset($b) ){
    //do common operations to both
    $both = $a+$b;
    if ($a_t){
    //do a operation
        $a = $a+5;
    }
     if ($b_t) {
         $b = $b+5;
      //do be operation
    }
}
echo "a=$a & b= $b & both=$both";
```

Comment: this should work but not for my use case.. mine is more like if (isset(a) || isset(b)... I'll try  and get a work around based on this  soultion. Thank you

Comment: @BadmusTaofeeq but it should also work with `isset()`, see my edited answer